# Como substituir variáveis com valores NA por ZERO dentro de um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Digamos que tenho um data.frame 6x5, exemplo:

```
print(Dados)

Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3   NA  2   4
L2     1   NA  1   NA  1
L3     NA  NA  2   3   4
L4     2   4   5   NA  9
```

Mas quero substituir os valores "NA" do data.frame por Zeros, exemplo:

```
    Linha  A   B   C   D   E
    L1     4   3   0   2   4
    L2     1   0   1   0   1
    L3     0   0   2   3   4
    L4     2   4   5   0   9
```

Como posso fazer para substituir as variáveis com valores NA por ZERO dentro do meu data.frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Também é possível solucionar o problema com `tidyverse`. Primero, crio um exemplo reprodutível:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  a = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 4), 
  b = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA)
)
```

Com `dplyr` fica assim:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  mutate_all(coalesce, 0)

  a b
1 0 1
2 1 2
3 0 3
4 2 0
5 4 0
```

Com `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

dataset %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)

  a b
1 0 1
2 1 2
3 0 3
4 2 0
5 4 0
```

Solução `r base`:

```
replace(x = dataset, list = is.na(dataset), values = 0)

  a b
1 0 1
2 1 2
3 0 3
4 2 0
5 4 0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 5):

Para substituir qualquer coluna com `NA` por 0, basta fazer:

`Dados[is.na(Dados)] <- 0`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 1):

por exemplo df

você pode fazer assim simplesmente sem a necessidade de criar uma coluna pelo comando mutate:

```
library(tidyverse)    
k <- c(1,2,80,NA,NA,51)
j <- c(NA,NA,3,31,12,NA)

df <- data.frame(k,j)%>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)#coverte todo data.frame
print(df)
```

resultado

```
k   j

1   0           
2   0           
80  3           
0   31          
0   12          
51  0
```